# Get minimum values only for duplicates in table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have the following SQL:

```
set @arbitraryMin = 'two weeks ago';
set @myDesiredMinimumTime = 'thisMorning';

select distinct order, box from db.table 
where scantime >= @arbitraryMin
having min(scantime) >= @myDesiredMinimumTime
```

Essentially, we have a system where it is possible that there are multiple scans for a distinct box/order combo. I only want to get the ones where the minimum scantime is >= @myDesiredMinimumTime. The query above returns two columns with no values in them. I can do this with a sub query, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this without using one.

I am no SQL guru, so I appreciate any help. Table sample (sorry for format):

scantime | Order | Box

2017-06-29 12:34:56 | 123456 | 123

2107-06-29 12:12:12 | 123456 | 124

2017-06-28 14:50:00 | 123456 | 123

Note the two duplicate order/box combos on different days on rows 1 and 3. If I input my query with @arbitraryMin = '2017-06-28 00:00:00' and @myDesiredMinimumTime = '2017-06-29 00:00:00', I only want to get the last two rows, as the top one is a duplicate scan at a different time.

Thank you

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Also add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to the question. This is to help future visitors and to avoid confusion. If the question is already solved with another answer, consider accepting/upvoting said answer. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I posted a solution. Let me know if this is not ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a invalid SQL. You can't have a `HAVING` clause without `GROUP BY`. So the below line is faulty

```
having min(scantime) >= @myDesiredMinimumTime
```

You should put that condition in `WHERE` clause only

```
where scantime >= @arbitraryMin
and (select min(scantime) from db.table) >= @myDesiredMinimumTime
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to upvote, but my rep not high enough. Ill put an edit with my revised query; I think I got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to Rahul.
I have found a solution:

```
select distinct order, box from db.table
where scantime <= @maxTime
group by ordernumber, boxnumber
having min(scantime) >= @myDesiredMinimumTime
```